# Swift: Alamofire: e_invalid_json

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I'm working on a company project who use Alamofire to connect to a Dittofi API.

I'm getting a 0 status code and a weirdly null output. Heres the code (I can only release this as per my NDA):

```
self.manager.upload(multipartFormData: {
            multipartFormData in
            for (key, value) in params{
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, to: createAssignmentURL, encodingCompletion: {
            (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON {
                    response in

                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let j):
                        let json = JSON(j)
                        print("JSON: ", json)
                        let message = json["statusMessage"].stringValue
                        let status = json["statusCode"].intValue
                        let data = json["data"]

                        if status == 200{
                            completion(message,"",status)
                        }else{
                            let errorMessage = data["error_msgs"].stringValue
                            self.reportError(message: errorMessage)
                            completion(errorMessage,"",status)
                        }

                        
                    case .failure(let error):

                        if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {

                            completion(App.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,"",App.STATUS_TIMEOUT)
                            
                        }
                        else if error._code == NSFileNoSuchFileError {


                            completion(App.INVALID_RESPONSE,"",App.STATUS_INVALID_RESPONSE)
                                                    }
                        else {

                            completion(App.INVALID_RESPONSE,"",App.STATUS_INVALID_RESPONSE)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                    
                if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    completion(App.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,"",App.STATUS_TIMEOUT)
                }
                else if error._code == NSFileNoSuchFileError {
                    completion(App.INVALID_RESPONSE,"",App.STATUS_INVALID_RESPONSE)
                }
                else {
                    completion(App.INVALID_RESPONSE,"",App.STATUS_INVALID_RESPONSE)
                }
            }
        })
```

Heres the output:

```
JSON:  {
  "data" : null,
  "error" : {
    "message" : "",
    "param" : "",
    "code" : "e_invalid_json"
  }
}
```

I'm certain something is wrong with the way I post but I cant seem to figure it out. I also get a 0 status code which apparently means that the response is empty. Is this a problem with my code or the API?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `multipartFormData`? You seem to need to send a `[String: String]`, shouldn't you need to send JSON (explaining why you have a response `e_invalid_json`)?

Comment: Is there a way to post as a JSON..? The code appends a key and value from a dictionary so it does eventually become `[String: String]`

Comment: When you use mutliformPartData, you send the parameters in a specific way. Usually, it's used for sending long/heavy data, like images, videos, big files. Here I guess you have just some parameters (a light dictionary). So don't use mutliformPartData. See how to send JSON: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#post-request-with-json-encoded-parameters